# Leaflet AJAX Map FitBounds

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, fitbounds

I am searching for a solution to fit a leaflet map's bounds to display the content of a loaded geoJSON file.

For loading the file I use leaflet-ajax. I tried already this, but I have no idea how I can get the layer's bounds. Any Suggestions how I can adjust the displayed map sector to display the geoJSON file? Thanks.

```js
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('http://localhost:8080/test.geojson');
geojsonLayer.addTo(this.map);
this.map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
```

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle of the entire code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AJAX means [asynchronous](http://www.macwright.org/2013/07/10/how-callbacks-work.html): so the fitBounds call will run *before* the content is loaded. To do this correctly, you'd wait for the data:loaded event.

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('http://localhost:8080/test.geojson');
geojsonLayer.addTo(this.map);
geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function() {
  this.map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
}.bind(this));
```

With the `.bind(this)` because the callback will [have a different this value by default](http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your bind(this) hint. You helped me a lot. Had to do a little modification and now it's working:
`var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(url);`
    `geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function() {`
        `this.map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());`
        `geojsonLayer.addTo(this.map);`
    `}.bind(this));`